How to use Hilt in com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.LauncherActivity?
I'm working on an Android project where I'm using com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.LauncherActivity as the main activity to launch a Trusted Web Activity (TWA). I want to inject a dependency (e.g., AdIdUtil) using Hilt into this activity.
Here's a simplified version of my activity code:
@AndroidEntryPoint
public class LauncherActivity extends com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.LauncherActivity {
    
    @Inject
    AdIdUtil adIdUtil;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        adIdUtil.sendAdId(); // Using the injected dependency
    }
}

When I try to run this, I get the following error:
[Hilt] Activities annotated with @AndroidEntryPoint must be a subclass of androidx.activity.ComponentActivity. (e.g. FragmentActivity, AppCompatActivity, etc.)

It seems that LauncherActivity from the androidbrowserhelper library doesn’t extend ComponentActivity, so Hilt can't inject dependencies directly into it.
What I’ve Tried
1 - Wrapper Activity: I created a wrapper activity that extends AppCompatActivity, and used it to handle dependency injection with Hilt, then launched LauncherActivity from the wrapper. This works but isn't ideal as I’d prefer to avoid an extra activity if possible.
2 - Manual Injection with EntryPoints: I attempted using Hilt’s EntryPointAccessors API to manually inject dependencies, which works but feels cumbersome for a straightforward injection.
3 - ViewModel Approach: I created a ViewModel to hold the dependency (AdIdUtil) and injected it there, but since com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.LauncherActivity doesn’t implement ViewModelStoreOwner, I encountered issues when trying to retrieve the ViewModel.
Question
Is there an alternative approach to use Hilt for dependency injection in com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.LauncherActivity without needing a wrapper activity? Or, is there a recommended way to handle dependency injection for classes that don't extend ComponentActivity?
Any guidance on this would be appreciated!
